# Spring Boot: How to test a class which is using gson object using autowiring

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, gson, junit5

I am new to JUnit and unit testing in java. I am having an issue while testing my code. Any help is appreciated.

My java class: `AService.java`

```
@Service
public class AService {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    public MyEntity getEntity() {
        String jsonResponse = serviceB.getResponse();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, MyEntity.class);
    }
}
```

My test class: `AServiceTest.java`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @InjectMocks
    private AService aService;

    @Test
    public void getEntityTest() {
        String serviceBResponse = "{\"id\":55,\"name\":\"My entity\",\"address\":\"XYZ\"}";
        when(serviceB.getResponse()).thenReturn(serviceBResponse);

        MyEntity entity = aService.getEntity();
        assertEquals("My entity", entity.getName());
    }
}
```

This is giving NullPointerException because `gson` object is not getting initialized. Also we can not mock `gson` as `Gson` class is `final`.

How can I test this code. I am using **spring boot** and **junit5.**

Comment: That's because you aren't using Spring in your test. Convert your class to using constructor injection instead of field injection, and the problem will be trivial to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend mocking `Gson` instead of that you can create and set the `Gson` object using `RefelectionUtils` and mock other dependency services

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AServiceTest {

   private ServiceB serviceB = Mocktio.mock(ServiceB.class);

   private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

  
   private AService aService = new AService();

   @Before
   public void setup() {
     ReflectionTestUtils.setField(aService, "serviceB", serviceB);
     ReflectionTestUtils.setField(aService, "gson", gson);
  }

   @Test
   public void getEntityTest() {
    String serviceBResponse = "{\"id\":55,\"name\":\"My entity\",\"address\":\"XYZ\"}";

    when(serviceB.getResponse()).thenReturn(serviceBResponse);
  
    MyEntity entity = aService.getEntity();
    assertEquals("My entity", entity.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: First approach will not work as it will give org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class com.google.gson.Gson
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class

Comment: oops i missed it, but updated the answer and that should work @RishabhSairawat

Answer (score 3):

A better way for testability is to have the `Gson` object passed to a constructor of the service (i.e. [constructor dependency injection](https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring)):

```
private ServiceB serviceB;

private Gson gson;

@Autowired
AService(ServiceB serviceB, Gson gson) {
    this.serviceB = serviceB;
    this.gson = gson;
}
```

Spring would still inject the `Gson` object as normal using the [`GsonAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.html) configuration class. In your test, however, you can now construct the `AService` using a regular `Gson` object:

```
AService aService = new AService(serviceB, new GsonBuilder().create());
```

Note: I've used `new GsonBuilder().create()` to create the `Gson` object because this is what `GsonAutoConfiguration` does to inject it in production. But you should also be able to create it using simply `new Gson()`:

```
AService aService = new AService(serviceB, new Gson());
```

Comment: Note that `@Autowired` isn't required if the class has only one constructor.